# How to check what is version of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know version of running SQL Server. would you please help on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect to the instance of SQL Server, and then run the following query:

```
Select @@version
```

An example of the output of this query is as follows:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 
10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express 
Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )
```

As shown here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Yes, this is full version information, right down to the build number

Comment: As a note, The SP Level shown on older versions of SQL Server is actually the OS Service Pack level. You can still use the build number to look up the actual service pack level though.

Answer (score 3):

For a thorough list of version information and other properties, try [xp_msver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187372.aspx)

For example:

```
EXEC master..xp_msver
```

Which gives output of the form:

```
1   ProductName NULL    Microsoft SQL Server
2   ProductVersion  589824  9.00.4053.00
3   Language    1033    English (United States)
4   Platform    NULL    NT AMD64
5   Comments    NULL    NT AMD64
6   CompanyName NULL    Microsoft Corporation
7   FileDescription NULL    SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit
8   FileVersion NULL    2005.090.4053.00
9   InternalName    NULL    SQLSERVR
10  LegalCopyright  NULL    © Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
11  LegalTrademarks NULL    Microsoft® is a registered trademark of Microsoft Corporation. Windows(TM) is a trademark of Microsoft Corporation
12  OriginalFilename    NULL    SQLSERVR.EXE
13  PrivateBuild    NULL    NULL
14  SpecialBuild    265617408   NULL
15  WindowsVersion  248381957   5.2 (3790)
16  ProcessorCount  8   8
17  ProcessorActiveMask 8                 ff
18  ProcessorType   8664    NULL
19  PhysicalMemory  32768   32768 (34359439360)
20  Product ID  NULL    NULL
```

There is an entire knowledge base article about retrieving [SQL Server version information](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;321185) - in addition to the other answer, using `@@Version`, you can also use:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), 
       SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), 
       SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

The reason SERVERPROPERTY is sometimes preferred is that @@Version returns the `OS Service Pack` Level, *not* the`SQL Server Service Pack` level in older versions - see http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/69/posts/18272/sql-server-version-showing-incorrect-service-pack-information.aspx and http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1085701-324-1.aspx#bm1127863 for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following query for any version of SQL Server  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZcbb.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Kqa.png

```
SELECT
create_date AS 'SQL Server Installation Date',
DATEADD(DD, 180, create_date) AS 'SQL Server Expiration Date',
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel,
SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this code in your SSMS query and you will get the version of SQL Server

```
    SELECT @@Version
```